# List<XNode> retrieve certain Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following event:

```
private void listBox_Items_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox_Items.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(FileName);

            var doc = xDoc.Descendants("item")
                          .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == listBox_Items.Text)
                          .Select(x => x.Nodes())
                          .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
                          .ToList();
            XNode name = doc[0];
            XNode id = doc[1];
        }
    }
```

I have gotten `XNode name = doc[0];` to give me `<name value="Ruby Pouch I" />` but I'm looking to get just `Ruby Pouch I`

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to select the `value` attribute, you should do that:

```
var values = xDoc.Descendants("item")
                 .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == listBox_Items.Text)
                 .Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value)
                 .ToList();
```

There's no need to call `Nodes()` or `SelectMany` at all.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better approaches instead of zeroing down to XNode for sure.

But specifically in your case where you have `XNode` in hand with value set to `<name value="Ruby Pouch I" />`, typecast it to `XElement` and get attribute value like this:

```
string value = (name as XElement).Attribute("value").Value;
```

---

**UPDATE**:

For comment:

> Is it possible to put that in a For loop so I don't have to declare
>   each and every single one?

This is how you do it:

```
foreach(var element in doc.OfType<XElement>)
{
   string value = element.Attribute("value").Value;
}
```

OR

```
var values = doc.OfType<XElement>().Select(el => el.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: Is it possible to put that in a `For` loop so I don't have to declare each and every single one?

Comment: See the update in answer. Hope that's what you want.